# Is it possible to put a PayPal payment on a pending status using API

Tags: paypal, status

I want to implement a flow for transactions.
A buyer sends a payment to a seller but the seller will not receive the money until my server will approve it's ok and the buyer has received what they paid for.

Is it possible to do that using PayPal API?
If not, are there any alternatives?

I've read the PayPal documentation and didn't find something about it.
Wondering if there are any other options using PayPal or other companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal implements this with a feature called [Delay disbursement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/delayed-disbursement/).

You must have a live PayPal partner app and onboard sellers with the feature specified in order to use it.

Comment: I saw this note: "Funds are automatically disbursed to the seller after 28 days.". Do you know if it's possible to cancel/create a new order for it?

Comment: You can refund the transaction to the payer at any point (be it before or after disbursing)

Comment: Interesting, even if the money has already been transferred? If so, what's the point of the delay?

Comment: The point is to ensure fulfillment of the order/service, and refunding after disbursement requires the permission having been granted to issue refunds for that account.

Comment: Do you know how to I transfer the money to the seller after I approve that he provided what he needs to the buyer? I didn't find the endpoint for it

Comment: There isn't one besides what's documented there, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/delayed-disbursement/#link-disbursefunds

Comment: Yea, it was a bit hard to understand what should be the reference ID.

Comment: generate one or use the default, which is `default`